# Compiling error for linked list in c

Tags: c

I did my whole project in NetBeans on my mac and it works fine. Then I go to put it into terminal to submit it on our ssh server for school and its giving me a bunch of compilation errors. Did netbeans compile in c++ or something? I'm new to c so any help is certainly appreciated. Here's the code.

```
/* 
 * File:   LinkedList.c
 * Author: dpiganell
 *
 * Created on October 17, 2011, 2:31 PM
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct element{
    int i;
    struct element *next;
};

void insert(struct element**, struct element*);
void purge (struct element*, struct element*);
void printList(struct element*);
void printListBackwards(struct element*);

struct element *h;

int main() 
{
    // HEAD
    h = (element *) malloc(sizeof(element));
    h = NULL;

    // NEW VALUE
    struct element *n = NULL;

    // POINTER TO THE POINTER OF HEAD
    struct element **headPointer;
    headPointer = (element **) malloc(sizeof(element));

    int a;
    a = 1;
    while(a >= 0)
    {
        n = (element *) malloc(sizeof(element));

        printf("\nPlease enter an integer value: ");
        scanf("%d", &a);

        if(a >= 0)
        {
            n->i = a;
            n->next = NULL;
            headPointer = &h;

            insert(headPointer, n);

        n = n++;


      }
        printList(h);
        printListBackwards(h);
    }

    return 0;
}


void insert(struct element **head, struct element *n)
{
    element *nptr, *pptr, *cptr;
    // NEW POINTER, PREVIOUS POINTER, CURRENT POINTER

    nptr = (element *) malloc(sizeof(element));

    int purged;
    purged = -1;
    if(nptr != NULL)
    {
        nptr->i = n->i;
        nptr->next = NULL;

        cptr = *head;
        pptr = NULL;
    }

    while(cptr != NULL &&  n->i >= cptr->i)
    {
        if(cptr->i == n->i && purged != 1)
        {
            purged = 1;
            purge(cptr, pptr);
        }
        else
        {
            pptr = cptr;
            cptr = cptr->next;
        }
    }

    if(pptr == NULL && purged < 0)
    {
        nptr->next = *head;
        *head = nptr;
    }
    else if(purged < 0)
    {
        pptr->next = nptr;
        nptr->next = cptr;
    }
}


void purge(struct element *current, struct element *predecessor)
{
    element *ptr = (element *) malloc(sizeof(element));

    // ERASING THE HEAD
    if(predecessor == NULL)
    {
        if(current->next == NULL)
        {
            current->next = NULL;
            current->i = NULL;
            current = NULL;
            free(current);
            h = NULL;
        }
        else
             memcpy(current, current->next, sizeof(element));
    }

    // ERASING THE TAIL
    else if(current->next == NULL)
    {
        current->i = NULL;
        free(current->next);
        free(current);
        predecessor->next = NULL;
    }

    // ERASING ANYTHING IN THE MIDDLE OF THE LIST
    else
    {
        ptr = current->next; 
        predecessor->next = ptr;
        current->i = NULL;
        free(current->next);
    }
}

void printList(struct element *head)
{
    if(head == NULL)
        printf("The list is empty.");
    else
    {
        struct element *ptr;
        ptr = (element*) malloc(sizeof(element));    
        ptr = head;  

        int a;
        a = 1;
        printf("Forwards: ");
        while(a > 0)
        {
            printf("%d ", ptr->i);
            if((ptr->next) == NULL)
                a = -1;
            else
                ptr = ptr->next;

        }
    }
}

void printListBackwards(struct element *ptr)
{
    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        // DO NOTHING BECAUSE IT WILL BE PRINTED ALREADY THAT IT IS EMPTIED
    }
    else
    {
        element *cptr = (element *) malloc(sizeof(element));
        cptr = ptr;
        if(ptr->next == NULL)
            printf("\nBackwards: %d ", ptr->i);
        else
        {
            printListBackwards(ptr->next);
            printf("%d ", ptr->i);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, here are the errors. It works fine and compiles fine in netbeans.

```
LinkedList.c:14: warning: useless keyword or type name in empty declaration
LinkedList.c: In function `main':
LinkedList.c:26: error: `element' undeclared (first use in this function)
LinkedList.c:26: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
LinkedList.c:26: error: for each function it appears in.)
LinkedList.c:26: error: syntax error before ')' token
LinkedList.c:34: error: syntax error before ')' token
LinkedList.c:40: error: syntax error before ')' token
LinkedList.c: In function `insert':
LinkedList.c:65: error: `element' undeclared (first use in this function)
LinkedList.c:65: error: `nptr' undeclared (first use in this function)
LinkedList.c:65: error: `pptr' undeclared (first use in this function)
LinkedList.c:65: error: `cptr' undeclared (first use in this function)
LinkedList.c:68: error: syntax error before ')' token
LinkedList.c: In function `purge':
LinkedList.c:110: error: `element' undeclared (first use in this function)
LinkedList.c:110: error: `ptr' undeclared (first use in this function)
LinkedList.c:110: error: syntax error before ')' token
LinkedList.c: In function `printList':
LinkedList.c:153: error: `element' undeclared (first use in this function)
LinkedList.c:153: error: syntax error before ')' token
LinkedList.c: In function `printListBackwards':
LinkedList.c:179: error: `element' undeclared (first use in this function)
LinkedList.c:179: error: `cptr' undeclared (first use in this function)
LinkedList.c:179: error: syntax error before ')' token
```

Comment: You're trying to use a type that you didn't define.

Comment: Are you sure you're showing us the *exact* code that gave you those errors?  When I compile it, the first error I see is that `element` is undeclared (in C, that type's name is `struct element`).  I can't reproduce the errors you're seeing in C++ either.

Comment: @KeithThompson The errors aren't in C++. The question was answered though thanks for the help. I compiled it in netbeans in a c++ compiler and it worked. But when I used gcc it didn't work just to clear things up. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @iSelkiies i guess it is time to accept an answer.

Comment: Keith knows. But the program is supposed to be C, not c++. Also: you malloc() too much.

Comment: @wildplasser I'm sure I do. This is probably my 5th c program, first one ever with malloc(). Would you be so kind as to point out where I have malloced when I didn't have to?

Comment: I'd still like to know how you got those error messages for that source file.  There's nothing on or near line 14 that should cause a "useless keyword or type name in empty declaration" warning.

Comment: When i compiled it in ssh using the gcc compiler those were the errors that were returned. Don't really know much about C. Spent most of my college career programming in JAVA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C, this definition

```
struct element{
    int i;
    struct element *next;
};
```

has to be referred to as `struct element`. You get that right in some places, not all. A known idiom is:

```
typedef struct element { 
    int i;
    struct element *next;
} element;
```

Which typedefs `element` as `struct element` so you don't need to place `struct` in front of the type. This was so common that C++ kind of "does this for you" so `struct` is no longer needed.

Answer (score 4):

It's C, you cannot use bare `element`, it's `struct element`.

Answer (score 1):

Your issues are related to how you declare your `struct element` vs. how you use it.

```
typedef struct element{
    int i;
    struct element *next;
} element;
```

will give you more satisfactory results.

Alternately, you can leave your `struct` as it is, wherever you use a bare `element`, instead write `struct element`.

**BTW:**

This isn't related to your exact problem, but I thought I would share (as my compiler gave me a warning about it); you sometimes write:

```
current->i = NULL;
```

In this case, `i` is an integer.  In C, `NULL` is traditionally used *only* for pointer types.  So as not to confuse, you should either change the assignment to:

```
current->i = 0;
```

...or, if `i` actually *is* meant to point to memory somewhere (which given the context above, I presume it is not), declare it as a pointer type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to typedef your struct if you're going to use it that way.  Otherwise you need to use the struct keyword everywhere. Check [documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29)

So you want to say:

```
typedef struct element {
   int i;
   element *next;
} element;
```

when you declare element.  Otherwise the compiler doesn't know that element is a structure every time you use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
h = (element *) malloc(sizeof(element));
h = NULL;
headPointer = (element **) malloc(sizeof(element));
```

This is your first error. element is a struct tag, not a typedef. (this has been handled by the others.)

in the loop:

```
headPointer = &h;
```

Both pointers have been assigned (malloc()d) values. By re-assigning them, you lose the stuff what was previously malloc()d.

The 'headPointer' stuff is a good idea. It is a pointer that can point to other pointers. You can use it to let a called function alter the the value of on of the callers pointers. But your usage is not right. Normally the caller should do:

```
struct clown *pipo=NULL;
...
my_function( &pipo);
```

Inside the function, the caller's pointer can than be altered:

```
void my_function (struct clown **ppp) {
   ...
   *ppp = malloc (sizeof (struct clown));
   ...
 }
```

After the function returned, the caller can use the pointer, and it will hopefully point at the new clown.
That's all.